# how to pass a thread parameter as a reference instead of by value?

Tags: pthreads, pthread-join

```c
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

const int kMaxThreads = 10;

void * threadRoutine(void * threadArg) {
    int myThreadNumber = * ((int * ) threadArg);
    //(int)threadArg
    printf("threadRoutine()=>: this is thread number %d!\n", myThreadNumber);
    int sleepTime = random() % 20;
    sleep(sleepTime);
    printf("threadRoutine()=>: thread[%d] completed after sleeping %d [secs]!\n",
        myThreadNumber, sleepTime);
    pthread_exit((void * ) myThreadNumber);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[kMaxThreads];
    printf("main()=>: creating threads...\n");
    for (int jj = 0; jj < kMaxThreads; jj++) {
        if (pthread_create( & threads[jj], NULL, threadRoutine, (void * ) jj) != 0) {
            /* undefined reference to a pthread_create*/
        } else {
            printf("main()=>: created thread[%d]!\n", jj);
        }
    }
    printf("main()=>: waiting for threads to complete...\n");
    for (int jk = 0; jk < kMaxThreads; jk++) {
        void * currentThread;
        if (pthread_join(threads[jk], & currentThread) != 0) {
            /* undefined reference to a pthread_join*/
        } else {
            printf("main()=>: completed thread[%d]!\n", (int) currentThread);
        }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble, with creating and join a thread. I am also not sure about the syntax of how to pass a thread parameter by reference. code should print when a thread is created and how long it sleeps in thread routine.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: how do I pass thread parameter as a reference instead of by value? also I am getting errors when creating and joining a thread, I don't know if I passed the parameters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is doing "bad things" with the single argument that `pthread_create()` allows you to pass to the thread function. `pthread_create()` allows a single `void *` to be passed (which can and usually is derived by casting from something else). In your case, you are doing this:

```
pthread_create(..., (void * ) jj)
```

This takes the integer value stored in `jj`, reinterprets it as a `void *`, and this pointer is what gets passed to your thread function. Strictly speaking, reinterpreting an `int` as a `void *` is suspicious at best, but that's the way the PThreads API was designed.

In your thread function, though, you are doing this:

```
int myThreadNumber = * ((int * ) threadArg);
```

This takes the `void *` that you were passed, and reinterprets it as a pointer to `int` (a.k.a. `(int *)`), which is generally acceptable on most platforms, but will result in an `int *` with the value of `0`, or `1`, ... in your usage. You then attempt to dereference this pointer to get an `int`, with your `* ((int *) ...)`. On most modern systems, the first iteration of your loop will thus result in a null pointer dereference (although the NULL pointer is not guaranteed to have the numeric value 0, it generally does on most systems/compilers these days), and will probably lead to a program crash as a result, unless you are catching and ignoring the relevant signals, etc.

What you should do in your thread function is cast the `void *` back to *exactly what it was cast from* to begin with. In other words, `int myThreadNumber = (int) threadArg`. Alternatively, you could call `pthread_create(.... (void *) &jj)` instead, if you really want a pointer to the `int` so you can pass information back - but that doesn't seem to be what you're trying to do here, and passing a pointer to a stack-based local variable would be a bad thing in other ways.

I'm not sure what you expect regarding being able to pass an argument by reference vs. value. The API states that you must pass a `void *`, so that's what you must do, unless you want to petition the PThreads folks to change the API... Or write your own...

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in:

```
  pthread_create( & threads[jj], NULL, threadRoutine, (void * )jj) ;
```

Is casting the `int jj` to `void*`, and passing that *value* to your `threadRoutine()`.  This is reasonable enough.  The problem appears to be that in `threadRoutine()` you:

```
  int myThreadNumber = * ((int * ) threadArg);
```

which is what we call "a mistake".  What to should do is:

```
  int myThreadNumber = (int)threadArg ;
```

or possibly:

```
  int myThreadNumber = (intptr_t)threadArg ;
```

to cast the `void*` pointer *value* back to the `int` it was.

To pass the `jj` by reference requires something along the lines of:

```
  int thread_arg[kMaxThreads] ;

  for (int jj = 0; jj < kMaxThreads; jj++) {
    thread_arg[jj] = jj ;
    if (pthread_create( & threads[jj], NULL, threadRoutine, &thread_arg[jj]) != 0) {
        /* undefined reference to a pthread_create*/
    } ...
```

And then you original

```
  int myThreadNumber = * ((int * ) threadArg);
```

can pick up the value.

Of course, the thread is entitled to use the thing pointed at by `threadArg` at any time while it is running... so you need to make sure it remains valid for that long.  In this case the `thread_arg[jj]` is only used by the 'jj'th thread, and remains in existence until after that thread has beem joined... so all is well.